# Offset of a member variable inside a struct

Tags: c, compiler-construction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [offsetof at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379298/offsetof-at-compile-time)

How can I find the offset of a member within a struct in C? For example, how can I find the offset of `t` in this struct:

```
struct test
{
  int a;
  int b;
  struct test* t;      
  int c;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `offsetof()` macro from `stddef.h`: `offsetof(struct test, t)`.  ([ideone example](http://ideone.com/BZ2Hv))

Comment: #define offset_of(TYPE , MEMBER) ((size_t) &((TYPE*)0)->MEMBER)

It seems like dereferencing a null pointer.
How does this helps in finding the offset.

Comment: It does, but the outer `&` (address-of) operator effectively "undoes" the dereference.  The overall expression asks "what address would MEMBER be at if there was a TYPE instance at memory location 0?"