# Determining struct member byte-offsets at compile-time?

Tags: c++, struct, offset, compile-time, offsetof

I want to find the byte offset of a struct member at compile-time.  For example:

```
struct vertex_t
{
    vec3_t position;
    vec3_t normal;
    vec2_t texcoord;
}
```

I would want to know that the byte offset to `normal` is (in this case it should be `12`.)

I know that I could use `offsetof`, but that is a run-time function and I'd prefer not to use it.

Is what I'm trying to accomplish even possible?

**EDIT**: `offsetof` is compile-time, my bad!

Comment: Why you don't want to use `offsetof`?

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira Because it is a run-time function, I'd prefer this information to be gathered at compile-time so I don't need to use CPU cycles.

Comment: `offsetof` is calculated at compile time. The C++ standard defers to the C standard, and the C standard says that it "expands to an integer constant expression" according to 7.17(3).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`offsetof` is a compile time constant, if we look at the draft C++ standard section `C.3` *C standard library*  paragraph *2* says:

> The C++ standard library provides 57 standard macros from the C library, as shown in Table 149.

and the table includes `offsetof`. If we go to the C99 draft standard section `7.17` *Common definitions*  paragraph *3* includes:

> offsetof(type, member-designator)
>
> > which expands to an integer constant expression that has type size_t, the value of
> >     which is the offset in bytes [...]

Comment: Bingo. I wonder if this is a C99 feature? (Being ICE, not the macro itself.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter well the draft C89 text linked from this [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18282656/1708801) has the same langauge.

Answer (score 4):

**In C:**

`offsetof` is usually actually a macro, and due to its definition, it will probably optimized by the compiler so that it reduces to a constant value. And even if it does become an expression, it is small enough that it should cause almost no overhead.

For example, at the file `stddef.h`, it is defined as:

```
#define offsetof(st, m) ((size_t)(&((st *)0)->m))
```

**In C++:**

Things get a bit more complicated, since it must resolve offsets for members as methods and other variables. So `offsetof` is defined as a macro to call another method:

```
#define offsetof(st, m) __builtin_offsetof(st, m)
```

If you need it only for structs, you are good enough with `offsetof`. Else, I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Those are *sample* definitions. The standard doesn't specify how `offsetof` is defined, just how it behaves.

Comment: In C++ `offsetof` is undefined except on a standard-layout struct. "Optimized" to a constant value still wouldn't make it an integral constant expression.

Comment: @KeithThompson You are right. I took these definitions from the version of libc I'm using right now.

Comment: @Potatoswatter You are right. The way I understand it, every modern compiler with the appropriate flags is very likely to reduce the whole expression to a constant value, since it is very likely to become an expression with only constants operands. I should be more clear in my answers. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: In C, `offsetof` is *required* to be a macro, and it's required to expand to an integer constant expression.  See [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 7.19 paragraph 3. C++ also requires `offsetof` to be a macro (C++12 18.2 [support.types]). C++ adds a paragraph of description on top of what it inherits from C; I don't know C++ well enough to tell whether the C++ rules imply `offsetof` must expand to an integer constant expression.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is run-time?

The following works..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>


struct vertex_t
{
    int32_t position;
    int32_t normal;
    int32_t texcoord;
};

const int i = offsetof(vertex_t, normal); //compile time..

int main()
{
    std::cout<<i;
}
```

Also see here: [offsetof at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379298/offsetof-at-compile-time)

Comment: In C++ the initializer of a `const int` doesn't need to be determined at compile time. Try using `offsetof` as an array bound instead.

Comment: From: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436300/are-constant-c-expressions-evaluated-at-compile-time-or-at-runtime  `The implementation is free to calculate it at runtime, but it must also be able to calculate it at compile time, because

it must give a diagnostic message if a constant expression is not representable in the type that its expression has and if
such expressions are allowed in contexts that require the value at translation time, for example if used as the size of an array dimension.` So yes it does need to be determined at compile time.

Comment: No, the initializer of a `const` object is not a constant expression.

Comment: offsetof expands to a constant expression. Since when is a "primitive type" an object? If it is not a constant expression then it is just a constant value assigned at compile time.

Comment: Instances of primitive types in C and C++ are called objects just like instances of class type. C requires resolution at compile time but C++ will perform any runtime task you want. Try `std::ostream &my_os = std::cout << "hello, world\n";`.

Comment: Since we now have `constexpr`, you should use that if you want to make sure it's computed at compile time.