# About offsetof usage in C and C++?

Tags: c++, offsetof

In C, I saw some usage of offsetof to calculate the offset of a member in the structure to its beginning?

Is it still recommended to use in C++? Any other way to do this without this macro?

Comment: offsetof [can be used in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19943445/1708801) with the restrictions that `If type is not a standard-layout class (Clause 9), the results are undefined` and `The result of applying the offsetof macro to a field that is a static data
member or a function member is undefined.`.

Comment: You should ask yourself seriously why you need the functionality of the "offsetof" macro. It is available in C++, but it will give unexpected results for non-POD structs and classes. If you don't know what a POD is then you better not use it in C++ code. You probably better not use it in C code either unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: Why is everyone discouraging its use? It is useful when calculating offsets for inline assembly or for calculating offsets of a POD structure that can change (TEB structure of WINAPI in Winternl.h) and for calculating offsets in x32 vs. x64 code without hardcoding the offsets..

Comment: There is no harm in using it if you need it. I would advise against creating your own implementation if this is exactly what you need. It has official support in the C++ standard. I would suggest that you think about your design a bit more to see if you really need it.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: the real question, however, is *why would you need to know* ? I cannot, at the moment, think of a single problem that *requires* its use.

Comment: @MatthieuM. that is the problem with the question and the answers is we don't understand the use case.

Comment: @MatthieuM. You really can't come up with ONE use-case? http://pastebin.com/7YZk26XK  <--- Reading the PEB and TEB structure. With almost every windows revision, the offsets change. In case you are wondering, reading these structures let you know the reference count to a .dll, which .dll's are loaded in a process, their offsets and various different information about them. You can also HIDE a .dll in the process or unlink it. There are many legit use-cases for offset-of.. The above code produces the following output: http://i.imgur.com/DXacFdG.png  and http://i.imgur.com/itIDAT2.png

Comment: And to support my comment above, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813706(v=vs.85).aspx  It states the structure may change in future releases.. I've seen it change a lot. Currently, the structure looks like: http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Process/PEB.html  There are MANY more where that came from. TEB being one.. Diving into the world of undocumented WINAPI and changing structures makes offsetof one of the most valuable assets. Check out the MSDN link and read the post at the very bottom..

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: I feel the need to point out that a function `void readLdr(HANDLE ProcessHandle, PEB_LDR_DATA* out);` could handle this with a much cleaner API.

Comment: I wasn't able to find such a function anywhere online :S If you mean that I could write on then yes I completely agree that what I posted is absolutely dirty.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726351/can-i-avoid-using-offsetof-in-the-following I link this question

Comment: Since a lot of friends said offsetof is not recommmeeded, can the above question gets solved?

Comment: @AdamLee the main problem is that we don't understand the problem you are trying to solve. If you can explain why you think you need `offsetof` you may get a better answer.

Comment: Similar topic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400116/what-is-the-purpose-and-return-type-of-the-builtin-offsetof-operator

Answer (score 1):

C++ has pointers to members. These are similar to offsets, but (1) typesafe and (2) more generic - they also work with methods, on base classes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Offsetof is a feature that is only in the C++ standard for C compatibility so **it is not reccomended** to be used in C word

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend it for anything, unless you really need to. So long as your use is valid in C, it should be valid for C++. Without knowing what you are doing, your question is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not.

Proper `C++` style encourages user to avoid all low-level details when possible. This is both for safety/correctness and readability. Only when low-level manipulation guarantees real and significant performance improve should one jump into it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the usages of `offsetof()` was in C-like code having structures with a fixed header, and variable size arrays, like explained in this blog post:

> [Why do some structures end with an array of size 1?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/26/220873.aspx)

(Note that this blog post uses the `FIELD_OFFSET` macro, which is a Windows-ism, corresponding to `offsetof()`.)

I think in modern C++ we should use *higher-level* techniques and code, like **`std::vector`** for variable sized arrays.