# Can I avoid using offsetof in the following?

Tags: c++, opengl-es, glkit

Following another question from me, here is a specific example where I want to avoid `offsetof`.

For using with `glVertexAttribPointer`, I have to use `offsetof` for the last parameter.

```
 glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex),
            (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, _color));
```

Vertex is a class. Is there a way I can avoid using this one? I tried with pointer to members, but no luck.

Cannot compile in the following

```
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex),
        (const GLvoid *)&Vertex::_color);
```

Comment: Why do you even want to avoid `offsetof`?

Comment: It is a pure C feature and i think C++ should have something better

Comment: that does not make sense. `offsetof` is specified in the C++ spec and thus as much a 'C++' feature as everything else.

Comment: It is just a macro,and I would like to see ono-macro solution. Someone said offsetof can be totally bypassed, I want to see if this can be done in this specific example.

Comment: It is a standard macro. So sure it can be bypassed. You can do the same thing the macro does. It typically involves ugly typcasting of NULL pointers, although modern compilers typically provide builtins for that anyway. There is nothing to gain here.

Comment: OP was discouraged by the posts here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22716560/about-offsetof-usage-in-c-and-c and wants a different solution to their problem.

Comment: OK, that might explain the reasoning behind the question. However, this is exaclty a case where those "low-level" details _must not_ be abstracted away, as the API in question is just defined on that low level.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the address of a non-static member qualified as `Vertex::_color`. You would need an instance of `Vertex`, but even then the address returned would be relative to the program's address space and this is not what you want when you use VBOs.

`offsetof (...)` is used is to find the address of an element in a data structure. This address does not point to actual memory, it is literally just an offset from the beginning of the structure (and this is why it uses `size_t` rather than `intptr_t` or `void *`).

Historically, when vertex arrays were introduced in OpenGL 1.1, it used the data pointer in a call to `glVertexPointer (...)` to reference client (program) memory. Back then, the address you passed actually pointed to memory in your program. Beginning with Vertex Buffer Objects (GL 1.5), OpenGL re-purposed the pointer parameter in `glVertexPointer (...)` to serve as a pointer to server (GPU) memory. If you have a non-zero VBO bound when you call `glVertexPointer (...)` then the pointer is actually an offset.

More precisely, the pointer when using VBOs is relative to the bound VBO's data store and the first datum in your VBO begins at address **0**. This is why `offsetof (...)` makes sense in this context, and there is no reason to avoid using it.