# What does (std::size_t)&((Structure *)0)->last do?

Tags: c

I recently came across this code and thought it was a little overkill.

```
struct Structure {
  unsigned int first;
  unsigned int last;
};
(std::size_t)&((Structure *)0)->last; // 4
```

So I'm wondering if I can safely do:

```
sizeof(unsigned int); // 4
```

instead of:

```
(std::size_t)&((Structure *)0)->last; // 4
```

or what that code is doing anyway if it's so much better.

**EDIT**

That code more or less euqals to `offsetof` as pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1379370/1001563
If you know what you're searching for you'll find the answer without having to ask. Thanks to @VladfromMoscow

Comment: Now add an `unsigned char middle;` between `first` and `last`. `(std::size_t)&((Structure *)0)->last` will now likely (not guaranteed) be 8. How would you update your `sizeof(unsigned int)` to give the right result here?

Comment: are you really 18 years old ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programs are usually being changed. So it is better to use a general approach. For example the type of data member first can be changed or before data member last there can be added one more data member.
Take into accpunt that there is already a similar macro in C defined in `<stddef.h>` (or `<cstddef>` in C++)

```
offsetof(type, member-designator)
```

Comment: doesnt the code actually output size of pointer of type of variable `last` inside `Structure`? If so, it is size of pointer on given machine, and that cant change unless you move the code to another computer/OS

Comment: @Creris The code outputs the offset of data member last within the structure.

Comment: Great so the best practice for something like this would be: `offsetof(Structure, last)`?

Comment: @mic Yes, it is better to use standard features.

Comment: Another advantage is that in the general case, if your structure is not `__attribute__((packed))` then you cannot know that its offset within the structure is the sum of the size of the preceding elements.